# How to make a else if statement if Process.Start fails

Tags: c#, windows, artificial-intelligence

So i'm working on a ai program right now. And for one of my commands i'm using Process.Start to open up a file. And I want to know how to make a else if statement base on if the Process.Start fails. I want it to run the block of code in the else if statement if the Process.Start failed. Does anyone know how? I'm sorry if I sound like a noob or somthen. I just started coding and i'm only 14 so I don't know that much yet.

```
        string r = e.Result.Text;



        if (r.Contains("your code"))
        {
            say("Opening up my code");
            Process.Start("C:/Users/Sukorow/Desktop/My Creations/Yuki Public Release/Yuki Public Release.sln");
        }
```

[Here's a image of the Process.Start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKRAT.png)

Comment: Please include your code in the question itself.  Asking people to open a new tab to look at an image *of text* is a bit much.

Comment: @BobKaufman - in this case, the Process.Start method *does*, in fact, return true or false to indicate whether or not the call succeeded, see the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking on guidance, how to write `if` statements isn't the type of programming problem you should be asking about here. This is not a beginner's tutorial site that teaches programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Process.Start returns true if it succeeded and false otherwise, so you could do:

```
var process = new Process()
{
       StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo()
       {
           FileName = "[your file]"
       }
};
if (!process.Start())
{
      // Handle the case where it didn't start
}
```

Also, as one more side-note, I don't recommend hardcoding the location of your .sln file in code. If you change your folder structure it'll break the application and anyone who you distribute the executable to will have to have the same exact folder structure as you or the call will fail. I recommend creating an App.config file, see the following documentation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184658.aspx

The basic idea is that you can add a key-value pair to store the location of the file - e.g.

```
<add key="folderName" value="C:\...."/>
```

That way you can modify this without having to recompile.

Comment: Thanks EJoshuaS for the comment above. It helped me out. And idk who down voted your answer.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: I downvoted because Your code does not compile. `Process.Start` does not return a `bool` it returns a `Process`

Comment: Yes Matt Wilko is correct, it does say that. But I used what you told me to use the try and catch and it worked out perfectly. So thx

Answer (score 0):

If you start a process using an ***instance*** of a `Process`, this returns a `bool` indicating whether it started or not:

```
        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("Notepad.exe");
        bool startedOk = proc.Start();
```

You also need to wrap this in a try catch block because attempting to start a process that does not exist throws an exception

Answer (score 0):

Just do a try catch.

```
{
    try
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files(x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"); 

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Make sure you have the application 
        installed.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
        MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
}
```